# Multiple inserts at same time in Yii

Tags: php, yii

im trying to create 2 records from the same model, in 2 diferent tables, my tables are *cruge_user* and *profile*, **The table profile (iduser ForeignKey) belongs to cruge_user (iduser PrimaryKey)** . So im working with the profile model ($model) and i import the cruge_user model ($modelCruge), the problem comes when I save a new record, i get 7 records in the DB, i notice that I also have 7 input in my _form.php so maybe is the reason but cant find the problem.

Here my action:

```
    public function actionCreate()
{
    $model=new Users;
    $modelCruge=new CrugeStoredUser;
    if(isset($_POST['CrugeStoredUser'], $_POST['Users']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['Users'];
        $modelCruge->attributes=$_POST['CrugeStoredUser'];


        if ($modelCruge->save(false)){
            $model->iduser = $modelCruge->iduser;
            $model->save(false);
        }

    }

    $this->render('create', array(
        'model'=>$model,
        'modelCruge'=>$modelCruge,
    ));
}
```

and here is my _form.php

```
    <div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($modelCruge,'username'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($modelCruge,'username'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($modelCruge,'username'); ?>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($modelCruge,'email'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($modelCruge,'email'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($modelCruge,'email'); ?>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($modelCruge,'password'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($modelCruge,'password'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($modelCruge,'password'); ?>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'name'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'name',array('size'=>45,'maxlength'=>45)); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'name'); ?>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'surname'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'surname',array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>100)); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'surname'); ?>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'rol'); ?>
    <?php $data = array(
        '1' => 'Padre',
        '2' => 'Profesor',
    ); ?>
    <?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'rol', $data); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'rol'); ?>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'idschool'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'idschool'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'idschool'); ?>
</div>


<br/>
<div class="row buttons">
    <?php echo CHtml::submitButton($modelCruge->isNewRecord ? 'Crear' : 'Guardar'); ?>
</div>
```

What i get in the DB when I submit is:

**Table cruge_user:**

iduser->1 , username->test, email->EMPTY, password->EMPTY...

iduser->2 , username->test, email->test@test.com, password->EMPTY...

iduser->3 , username->test, email->test@test.com, password->test...

iduser->4 , username->test, email->test@test.com, password->test...

iduser->5 , username->test, email->test@test.com, password->test...

iduser->6 , username->test, email->test@test.com, password->test...

iduser->7 , username->test, email->test@test.com, password->test...

**in Table profile:**

iduser->6 , name->test, surname->test, rol->1...

iduser->7 , name->test, surname->test, rol->1..

It creates 7 records in table cruge_user and 2 records in table profile :/
When its supossed to create only 1 record in table cruge:user and with the same iduser create a record in table profile with extra data.

Some help?

Comment: Could you add the code of CrugeStoredUser and Users model?

Comment: I just solved it, with another method but its woeking fine. I just copy and paste the code respective for registration from the UIcontroller in Cruge and adapted it to my needs, Thanks for your answer